# Проверка конфигурации nginx

Tags: nginx, macos, homebrew

Устновил `nginx` через `homebrew`. Знаю, что на `Ubuntu` проверить конфигурацию можно при помощи `configtest` через `service`:

```
pak@server: sudo service nginx configtest
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Возможно ли точно так же проверить на `OS X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Возможно ли точно так же проверить на OS X?

согласно [этому ответу](https://superuser.com/a/443914/454489) — нет.

но можно выполнить непосредственно то действие, которое производится упомянутой вами командой (возможно, потребуется указание полного пути к программе nginx):

```
$ sudo nginx -t
```